# Use site column (metadata) as search criteria in the out of box search box in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search, search-results, site-column, metadata

If I have a site column(metadata) called for example **state** set on a library, and I have uploaded some documents in my library with a value on that site column(metadata).  I will like to know if, Out of the box,  I can search documents typing: **state:AL** in the search the box and get the right  result mean **the document that has their state metadata set to AL**. just like we type **title: year** to get document that have their title with the word year?

I ask that because I tried search that way **State:AL** and I am not getting any result while I have such documents in my library.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should work, have the items been crawled by the search service since setting up the column and setting a value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Managed Property for the Search query to work. If you created a Site Column SharePoint Search will create a Managed Property for you based on the Site Column name. It all depends on the data type.

The details are here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx

If you did not use a site column, or want to use "State" then you can create a new Managed Property and title it State. Then add your crawled property "ows_State" to it. Once a full crawl runs you will be able to execute your desired query.

Comment: Thanks @erci alexander for your answer, But I don't have server access.

Comment: Hi Matthew  my column is a site column, I just read your link. and this mean that my column has a Managed property created with the name: SiteColumnNameOWSCHCS, as it is a  site column of type Choice, right? My questions  now is. -The full crawl is not something that may is automated, because I don't have server access? - Let say that the full crawl have been done, Is this how I should used my managed property in the search box to search in my library, by typing SiteColumnNameOWSCHCS: sought_keyword.

Comment: If you cannot create your own Manage Property, then yes, you can use the Automated Managed property for your query.